# How do I convert a pointer to double in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have written the following code that accepts population values separated by comma. Then, I split the string inputted and stores it into an array. Now, I want to store in a double so I could perform mathematical functions on it. But first, I want to output it as double. I have tried strtod but it give me an error of

```
passing argument 1 of '__strtod' makes pointer from integer without a cast    [-       Wint-conversion]
```

This is my main function

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  int p_size, s_size;
  int n =0;
  char *population;
  char population_string[100];
  printf("Enter the population size:");
  scanf("%d",&p_size);
  printf("Enter the sample size:");
  scanf("%d",&s_size);
  printf("Enter the population values separated by comma(,):");
  scanf("%s",&population_string);
  printf("The population are:%s\n",population_string);
  population = splitPopulation(population_string,p_size);
  printf("The contents are:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < p_size; i++)
  {
    printf("%c\n",population[i]);
    printf("%f\n", strtod(population[i],NULL));
  }
  return 0;
 }
```

and this is my function for splitting the string

```
char * splitPopulation(char *population_string, int size){
  char *population_array=malloc(sizeof(char*)*size);
  char *token = strtok(population_string,",");
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    population_array[i]= *token;
    token= strtok(NULL,",");
  }
  return population_array;
}
```

My sample inputs are:

```
Enter the population size:4
Enter the sample size:2
Enter the population values separated by comma(,):1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's work backward from splitPopulation. This function returns a pointer to char

```
char *
```

but what you're really returning is an array of pointers to char, which means the type is:

```
char **
```

In other words the return value is a pointer, and what it's pointing to is another pointer, which points to the first character of the first number in the comma-delimited population string.

So now population is a char ** instead of a char *, and population[i] is a char * instead of a char, so you can pass it to strtod. (You're seeing the warning about passing an int as a pointer because population[i] is currently a char and is being promoted to an int.)

You will also have to define population_array as a char **. When assigning population_array[i], just assign it to token without the deference operator.

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you for enlightening me about array of pointers to char.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing this:

```
strtod(population[i],NULL)
```

Where `population[i]` is a single `char` which is a number in ASCII.  You don't need a function to convert a single `char` from ACSII to an integer:

```
double pop_num = population[i] - '0';
```

That is, '0' becomes 0, and '1' becomes 1, etc.  See an ASCII table for why this works.

By the way, your malloc is allocating 4-8x more than needed, because it uses `sizeof(char*)` when your elements are actually `char` not `char*`.

Comment: The OP wants to tokenize a string of numbers into an array of strings (in other words, an array of pointers to char), not an array of chars. It wouldn't make sense to represent a population value as a single ASCII character, especially in light of the OP's desire to print it as a double.